# Bluetooth 3.0 connection on IOS using IAP2

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, mfi

Question: **Given MFI certified IAP2 support for Bluetooth 3.0, how can one connect, search and pair from withing the application?** What are the exact commands? An example would be best :)

Background:

We recently developed an ISO application that communicates an external HW device using Bluetooth 3.0 which as some of you know reuqires MFI (which we have)

One of the great drawbacks was the lack of the application to initiate the connection to the bluetooth device due to IOS limitations i.e. the user must manualy go to the iphone bluetooth settings and connect to the external HW device, unlike in adroid where given the external HW device Bluetooth name and assuming the user already paired the device the application can initiate the connection

After talking to the Bluetooth module manufacturer about this drawback he replied the BT module supports both IAP1 and IAP2 while one of the features of IAP2 was "Bluetooth connection", "searching" and even "paring" from within the application.

The probelm is that he couldn't tell us HOW? Hence the question above :)

Thank you &
Best Regards
Ran